# Python: Difference in list declaration for function returning a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So my function is returning a list which works fine as long as I define the class like this for a fixed number of values.
If I have only three elements in my searchKeys list and I define the returnList like `returnList = [0,0,0]` I can print the list when calling the function.
But if i try `returnList = []` I cannot print the list when I call the function.

```
returnList = [0,0,0]
    with open(logfile, "r") as currentFile: # open Eventlog
        for c, info in enumerate(searchKeys): # loop over searchKeys 
            counter = 0
            currentFile.seek(0)
            for line in currentFile: # loop over lines
                if info in line: # search for element
                    counter += 1
                    returnList[c] = counter # this is where I am trying to fill the
    return returnList
```

Comment: I think you left out the most important part of your program... the `#code to fill the list with n values ` part.

Comment: Something goes wrong, if only we knew what... [ask] [mcve]

Comment: we need a minimal working demonstration of your problem

Comment: I agree with coldspeed.  Also, you left out the most important part of your description.  What is the "something" that goes wrong?

Comment: Hope the description now is much clearer. Actually the code in between never changed just the definition of the list in very first line.

Comment: You still havent explained what "fails" means. Errors? invalid results? what *does* happen? Please read [ask]

Comment: returnList[c] if the list is empty : yes, that should make a problem.
Or even if c > 2 (your list being a 3 length list).  You should clearly look the answer of Sayse below, i'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you're getting an index out of range error since you try to access an element that doesn't exist in the list. Instead, use `append`

```
returnList[c] = counter
```

should be

```
returnList.append(counter)
```

Comment: That was what I need. In addition I had to take out the 'returnList.append(counter)' of the for loop one scope level higher.